# Error when calling oracle stored procedure using LSX

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus, connector

I copied the Sample LC LSX Agent to Call an Oracle Stored Procedure from the following.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_EXAMPLE_SAMPLE_LC_LSX_AGENT_TO_CALL_AN_ORACLE_STORED_PROCEDURE_9674_OVER.html

I modified the .Server, .username, etc with the relevant values. When I run the agent it generates the following error:

> "this operation cannot be performed on a fieldlist with no fields"

Following the Store Procedure (it works fine when run from sqlplus client)

```
PROCEDURE test_conn_txt1 ( p_in IN VARCHAR2 ,p_out OUT VARCHAR2) IS
l_out VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN 

   --p_out :=p_in;
   l_out := 'Testing';--||to_char(p_in);
   p_out := l_out;  
   insert into xx_test1 values (to_char(p_in),to_char(p_out));
   commit;

END ;
```

Following is the Agent code

```
Option Public
Option Explicit

UseLSX "*lsxlc"

Sub Initialize  
    Dim sess As New LCSession   
    Dim conn As New LCConnection ("oracle8")        

    'set the connection parameters...   
    conn.Server = "ora_prod"    
    conn.UserId = "user1"   
    conn.Password = "password"

    src.OracleTextFormat = "UTF8"


    'connect to the database... conn.Connect        
    'set the stored procedure owner and stored procedure name...    
    'conn.Owner = "OWNER"   
    conn.Procedure = "test_conn_txt1"
    conn.connect        

    'set Fieldnames property with any output parameters declared in the stored procedure... 
    'conn.Fieldnames = "p_out"      

    'declare any fields and fieldlists for input/output data... 
    Dim input_fieldlist As New LCFieldList  
    Dim output_parms As New LCFieldlist 
    Dim in_field_int As New LCField (1, LCTYPE_INT) 
    Dim in_field_text As New LCField (1, LCTYPE_TEXT)   
    Dim out1 As New LCField (1, LCTYPE_INT) 
    Dim out2 As New LCField (1, LCTYPE_TEXT)    
    Dim out As Double       

    'set the input parameters of the stored procedure...        
    Set in_field_text = input_fieldlist.Append ("p_in", LCTYPE_TEXT)    
    in_field_text.Text = "testing of stored procedure for input values"     

    'Set in_field_text = input_fieldlist.Append ("p_out", LCTYPE_TEXT)  
    'in_field_text.Text = "testing of stored procedure for input values"        

    Set out2 = output_parms.Append ("p_out", LCTYPE_TEXT)   
    out2.Text = "testing of stored procedure for input values"      


    'with the input parameters set, call the stored procedure...    
    'the declared output_parms fieldlist will hold the output parameters of the stored procedure... 

    out = conn.Call (input_fieldlist, 1, output_parms)  

    'fetch parameter(s) into the output_parms fieldlist...  

    out = conn.Fetch (output_parms)     
    'retrieve the parameter(s) from the output_parms fieldlist...   

    Set out1 = output_parms.GetField (1)    
    'Set out2 = output_parms.GetField (2)       
    'use the output parameter value(s) in your script...    

    Print "Output parameter 1 is " & out1.Value(0)  
    'Print "Output parameter 2 is " & out2.Text(0)      

    conn.Disconnect 

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to tell us which statement the script failed on.

Comment: The code fails at  out = conn.Fetch (output_parms)  after the out = conn.Call (input_fieldlist, 1, output_parms)  is made

Answer (score 0):

The call method only supports input parameters to a stored procedure.  If you want to output data from the stored procedure, you must put it into a result set.  the result set can then be read using the `Fetch` statement.

After additional research, I have found a conflict in the documentation.  You are just going to have to try some things and let us know how it works.

Here is a link: publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_148034CHAPTER_9_ORACLE_8_CONNECTOR.html

Try commenting out the lines in your agent that start with `Set out2 = ...` and `out2.Text = ...`.

Comment: I do understand the results fieldlist object has to be passed to .fetch to get the stored procedure output but the results field does not have any data. I ran the script and I get "this ooperation cannot be performed on a fieldlist with no fields" error because the results fieldlist object does not have any data. I was also told that lc lsx does not support oracle RECORD data type as an output. I guess an existing working sample code for reference will be helpful